# 7z2john can't be found after installation

Tags: linux

I ran `sudo apt install libcompress-raw-lzma-perl -y`. After that, I did `locate 7z2john` which resulted in:

> /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db: No such file or directory

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary database used by `locate` (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`)
is updated once daily by `cron`, so `locate` will not find new files,
especially if `locate` itself was only installed today.

You can fix this by running the command `sudo updatedb`.

This task may do heavy I/O.
If you wish the command to use I/O resources only when the disk is idle,
use the
[ionice command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)
like this :

```
 sudo ionice -c3 updatedb
```

Answer (score 2):

`libcompress-raw-lzma-perl` is a dependency required to run 7z2john. It does not install 7z2john.